# Run the same couchdb replication from two instances - possible?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am trying to replicate from isaacs couchdb, and It takes so long time.
I am thinking to spawn up another couchdb instance and to tell it to replicate from isaacs couchdb to my first instance.

Is this possible to run those two in parallel? will it speed up the replication process?

Thanks,
Yosi

Answer (score 1):

You can easily setup replication from and to remote instances doing:

```
POST /_replicate HTTP/1.1

{"source":"http://example.org/example-database","target":"http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/example-database"}
```

I am not sure if it will split the replication if you have both going at the same time. I am guessing it will just try to replicate all documents twice, getting a conflict the second time it attempts it.

I am not familiar with that DB, but what you can do to split the replication is let each instance replicate certain databases within isaacs. That will split the replication for you since each database will only get replicated once. If there is only one database, that isn't very helpful then.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking, will it split or not? I know how to replication from remote to remote.
I want to know will it split and will it be more efficient?

Comment: There is only one database,
I have started on two instances, and on one instance the progress is 21% and on the other is 22%

Comment: Did you start the replications at the same time?

Comment: Nope. The one with the 22% I started two days ago (it failed lots of time, and I restarted it.. We can say it run for 6 hours). The other one with 21% I started an hour ago